# ListAdding is not firing, but ListDeleting yes

Tags: event-receivers

I have an SPListEventReceiver on Custom List Definition in SharePoint 2013 that handles the ListAdding and ListDeleting events.

```
<Receivers   ListTemplateId="10002" >
<Receiver>
<Name>SceListAddListAdding</Name>
<Type>ListAdding</Type>
<Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
<Class>xxx.EventReceivers.SceListAdd.SceListAdd</Class>
<Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
<SequenceNumber>10100</SequenceNumber>
</Receiver>
<Receiver>
<Name>SceListAddListDeleting</Name>
<Type>ListDeleting</Type>
<Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
<Class>xxx.EventReceivers.SceListAdd.SceListAdd</Class>
<Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
<SequenceNumber>10101</SequenceNumber>
</Receiver>
...
```

I am creating list based on the definition through the SharePoint UI but this does not fire ListAdding(ListAdded) event. When I deleted this list ListDeleting(ListDeleted) event is firing OK

Help me please. Any Idea ?

Comment: ListAdding event is different from ListAdded event, now which event you want.?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Yes. I know. But it's the same behavior for both methods. Deleted and Deleting are firing Neither ListAdding nor ListAdded are firing I need a functional rather ListAdded